# How to do Fulltext search on the below Document with ArangoDB?

Tags: json, arangodb

```
{
  "rootElement": {
    "names": {
      "name": [
        "Haseb",
        "Anil",
        "Ajinkya",
        {
          "city": "mumbai",
          "state": "maharashtra",
          "job": {
            "second": "bosch",
            "first": "infosys"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "places": {
      "place": {
        "origin": "INDIA",
        "current": "GERMANY"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I had the document like the above example and I want to search the value like "mumbai" or "infosys" then how would I do the indexing and search for the same.

Answer (score 1):

As we already discussed in other questions, you can only index one field in the document.

How about using a [yaml dump](http://yaml.org/) of the whole structure in another attribute that you do the index on?

So, lets say paralell to `rootElement` you add `wordTokens` with that dump, and put a fulltext index on that?

You would probably want to use some regular expressions to strip keywords from the yaml dump, and since you don't want to be able to de-serialize it, remove unneeded whitespace and linebreaks too.

Comment: Yes I understood that I can index only one field in the document but here in this document if I have to search "bosch" on which field should I do the index to do full text search

Comment: I'm not sure if you can because job is inside an array, but it would be `rootElement.names.name[3].job` to index "bosch" and "infosys".

Comment: Did the answers work for you? if yes, can you mark the best of them as 'accepted'? If not, whats missing? Would you like to share your actual solution?